# Find & Delete directories in .zip files

Tags: zip

Question 1 : In many .zip archive files I would like to delete directories anwsering to a name pattern. 
In a "normal" directory I used :

```
find . -type d -name "pattern" -mtime +30| xargs rm -r
```

Is it possible to find/delete these directories without having to unzip the .zip files?

If I do have to unzip I have to zip them again after deleting those files, which I would like to avoid.

I saw a few topics which advised to mount .zip files to use shell commands. Could it work for me too ? (I'm quite new to the Unix World).

Question 2 : 
i did like Mark said and put everything in  a loop. It works fine but without asking for anything i get in the terminal for each deleted file/folder a line :
"deleting: blabla.txt".
How is it possible to get these lines in a log file ? Just adding >> ${logFile} after the command line would be enough ?

Comment: A zip archive is a compressed file. You can update them with a command like `jar` which follows a syntax similar to `tar`. You might also use a loopback filesystem, or a GUI archive manager.

Comment: Will `zip -d archivename.zip '*/pattern/*'` do what you want?

Comment: To answer the new question: yes, adding `>> ${logFile}` after the zip command will append all the "deleting:" messages to that file.

Answer (score 6):

As @MarkPlotnick pointed out, you can use glob patterns. From `man zip`:

```
zip -d foo foo/tom/junk foo/harry/\* \*.o
```

> will remove the entry foo/tom/junk, all of the files that start with  foo/harry/,  and
>                 all  of  the files that end with .o (in any path).

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot Mark, your solution works fine for a single test file. Now I'll try to do this in a loop. If i don't manage to do this on my own, I may come back to you. Have a nice day, Jean-Samuel